# Apps Disappearing from Home Screen and App Manager

Tags: applications

Does anyone of you knows why my apps disappeared on my home screen and my app manager? At first, I was just communicating with my friend via the messenger app then it suddenly crashed and my phone turned off. It, thankfully, switched on but the thing is my apps were gone. I tried rebooting my phone many times but they didn't come back. Then I tried installing the apps from my backup (first) then from the playstore but it says "app not installed". What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why your apps disappeared, but I think you're not able to reinstall them because of leftover data files. I used [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) to delete data corpses, in order to be able to reinstall some apps after flashing a rom.
Once installed, go to **CorpseFinder**, scan and then delete the corpses you find. You should then be able to reinstall your missing apps.

Answer (score -3):

Better wipe off your data and system partition and reflash the ROM you're using.

Comment: Did you consider Kyla might be a "beginner", and not know how to do what you're suggesting? Also, what makes you think a reflash is necessary, and e.g. a factory-reset wouldn't be sufficient? On a not-rooted device it's pretty unusual that something alters the `/system` partition (and thus making a reflash necessary).